# I would like to change to color of the font

Tags: html, css

Hi good day every one I am a beginner in html and css can anybody help me here of my code because i want to change the color of font in to black and the font size of my navbar but I couldn't change my code is in below

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> shoe Website</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-header">
      <a href="">About us</a>
      <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="">Contact us</a>
      <a href="">Terms of use</a>
      
      <div class="middle"> </div>
      <div class="space-end"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/Screenshot 2023-07-09 162710.png">
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">Shop</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">Pages</a></li>
          <li> <a href=""> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

this is my CSS code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

.top-header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #343a40;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
a{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F4EEE0;
  margin: 0;
}
a:hover{
  color: #176B87;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

body, html{
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.logo{
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  
}
ul, li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
}
```

I would like to expect that to change the color and the fonts  of  "Home, Shop , Pages, and Contact."

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UV7S.png)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

.top-header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #343a40;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
a{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F4EEE0;
  margin: 0;
}
a:hover{
  color: #176B87;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

body, html{
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.logo{
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  
}
ul, li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-header">
      <a href="">About us</a>
      <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="">Contact us</a>
      <a href="">Terms of use</a>
      
      <div class="middle"> </div>
      <div class="space-end"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">Shop</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">Pages</a></li>
          <li> <a href=""> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Assuming the CSS file is loaded correctly, the links should all be `#F4EEE0`, is that not the case on the page?

Comment: `i want to change the font color and the font of my navbar but I couldn't`. That doesn't explain much. Can you be more specific? What is the expected color? What color are you seeing now? Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Try this:  ```.navbar ul li a{color: orangered; font-family: monospace;}```

Comment: i already edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the color of `a` elements that are inside `li` elements by adding a color to `li`. That is not going to work because of css specificity ( you already add a color to `a` in your CSS file )

So, ' be more specific ' . You have 2 options:

1. add a rule `ul li a { color: ... }`  and that will change the color of your desired elements. and delete the `color`rule from `ul li`
2. or add `ul li a { color: inherit }` which will inherit the color from the parent

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

.top-header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #343a40;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
a{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F4EEE0;
  margin: 0;
}
a:hover{
  color: #176B87;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

body, html{
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.logo{
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  
}
ul, li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
}
ul li a { color: black } // or inherit
```

```html
<div class="top-header">
      <a href="">About us</a>
      <a href="">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="">Contact us</a>
      <a href="">Terms of use</a>
      
      <div class="middle"> </div>
      <div class="space-end"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">Shop</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">Pages</a></li>
          <li> <a href=""> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color and font size of the link text inside inside the class navbar:

```
.navbar a {
  color: black;
  font-size:15px; // change according to your needs
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to import your CSS into your document.

See [Link Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) for more info.

Edit - Fixed css rules, see bottom two rules.

```css
...
ul, li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I already edit my post kindly check the problem

Comment: Done, check altered answer, this is already pointed out by several others but here you go...